# Looping array inside list in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, loops

I have a list of arrays that contains multiple arrays.
Each array has 2 indexes.
First, I want to loop the list. Then I want to loop the array inside the list.

How can I do that ?

I tried to use this way, but it doesn't work:

```
 1. foreach (string[] s in ArrangList1)
 2. {
 3.    int freq1 = int.Parse(s[1]);
 4.    foreach (string[] s1 in ArrangList)
 5.    {
 6.       int freq2 = int.Parse(s1[1]);
 7.       if (freq1 < freq2)
 8.       {
 9.          backup = s;
10.         index1 = ArrangList1.IndexOf(s);
11.         index2 = ArrangList.IndexOf(s1);
12.         ArrangList[index1] = s1;
13.         ArrangList[index2] = s;
14.      }
15.      backup = null;
16.   }
17. }
```

It give me error in line 4.

I try to do the loop using other way, but I don't know how to continue.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ArrangList1.Count; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < ArrangList1[i].Length; j++)
   {
      ArrangList1[i][1];
   }
}
```

I use C#.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you post the error message you are getting from code block #1?

Comment: ...and for the benefit of others, please accept some of the answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 4):

The error in line4 might be due to a typo using ArrangList. I think you only have ArrangList1 defined. Regardless, the logic is wrong. If you have a list containing arrays, you want to do a foreach on the list, then a foreach on each list item (which is an array).

It's not clear what your types are, so I'm assuming that ArrangList is a list of string arrays.

```
foreach(string[] s in ArrangList1)
{
  foreach(string innerS in s)
  {
      //now you have your innerString
      Console.WriteLine(innerS);
  }

}
```

In your second example,

You have a typo as well...

```
for (int i = 0; i < ArrangList1.Count; i++)

       {

           for (int j = 0; j < ArrangList1[i].Length; j++)

           {

               ArrangList1[i][1]; //the 1 here should be j

           }

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LINQ and one foreach loop:

```
// assuming ArrangList1 is List<string[]>

var query = from a in ArrangList1
            from b in a
            select b;

foreach (String s in query)
{
    System.Console.Writeline(s);
}
```